# How to access json object which is array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting the following error response in my ajax logging form (Laravel 5.2)
`{"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}` with status code of `422`
I tried to access the message in `.fail` block of jQuery Ajax by using `data.responseText.email[0]` but i am getting `undefined` error.
I don't know what I am missing here.
In short how can I access the messages, so that I can show in dom?

Below is snippet of my fail block.

```
.fail(function(data) {

   $('.modal-error-msg').html(data.responseText.email[0]).fadeIn();

})
```

Comment: `responseText`, contains `Text` (or more precisely, a string), not a javascript object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `data.responseText` is a String, not a Json Object, You need to [cast](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it into a Json:

```
var jsonValue = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
$('.modal-error-msg').html(jsonValue.email[0]).fadeIn();
```

You could avoid this problem, if server would return a message with

`Content-type: application/json`.

Comment: It's not so much a cast as it is parsing the text to a JavaScript object. JSON is a string format of an object. Also, `Json` should be `JSON`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is not responsiveText, its `responseText`. The solution work for me.
I am sure `header` contain `Content-Type: application/json`.
Is there any way to access it without parsing it ?